# Bootstrap Carousel Is Displaying All Images On Top of Each Other

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my head I have

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```

And my carousel code looks like this:

```
<section class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" class="active" data-slide-to="0"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                </ol>
                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="planet-earth.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="planet-earth.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="planet-earth.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="planet-earth.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="planet-earth.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

But all the images are appeared stacked on top of each other.

In my folder I have:

- bootstrap.min.js
- jquery-3.2.1.js
- main.js
- main.js
- planet-earth.jpg
- star_home.html
- style.css

EDIT: I'm displaying my page in Google Chrome.
EDIT 2: I changed what my head looks like now. This currently works but it also make the header I have out of place. Specifically it centers the entire header and makes it not extend to the ends of the page. When I use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

as the Bootstrap link (the optional Bootstrap link) it looks like how I want to but then the carousel doesn't work.

Comment: bootstrap.min.js needs to be loaded after jquery-3.2.1.js. You're also missing a doctype and the viewport meta tag. You might want to start with their suggested template: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#template

Comment: I had the DOCTYPE but just didn't include it. I added everything from the template and changed the load order of the javascript files to jQuery, Bootstrap, then main.js and it's still displaying all images atop each other.

Comment: @ChristopherBerry, Also change the order of your CSS styles to load bootstrap's first, and then yours.

Comment: Okay, so a) update your question to match what you're working with, and b) have you checked the developer console for errors? (press the F12 key while in your browser).

Comment: There are no errors in the developer console. Also I'm displaying my page in chrome.

Comment: Your code (as shown) still is missing the tags Bootstrap requires, and your scripts are still out of order. It's going to be hard to give you a better suggestion (or an actual answer) without seeing what you're working with.

Comment: For reference, this is a jsFiddle showing that your markup (for the carousel) is fine: https://jsfiddle.net/9k73xj3o/ - you're not mixing different versions of Bootstrap, are you?

Comment: So it looks like it's the Bootstrap link I'm using. When I use the latest compiled and minified link the carousel works but it messes with my header and when I use the optional link the header looks fine but then the carousel doesn't work.

Comment: You can't mix Bootstrap 3 and Bootstrap 4 - 4 uses a lot of flexbox rules that require slightly different markup than 3, and some classes are different (Bootstrap 4 carousel items use `carousel-item` instead of `item`, for instance).

Comment: "messes with my header" - you're not showing that. Try to include enough to demonstrate whatever issue you're seeing, if you want more than wild guesses, which is the best I can offer at the moment.